# php echo data to html performance

Tags: php, html, mysql

I add some Data in form of a table to my website. Actually everything works but i wanted to test the performance for some big data. It was very bad. Here my Results:

```
tablesize | time
-----------------
10x20     | 0.22s
100x20    | 3.29s
1000x20   | 28.75s
```

My question is which way is better to show the results and why:

1:

```
<?php
   for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){
       echo "<div id='...' class='...Ä style='...'>"
       for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){
           echo "<div style='...'>".array[$i][$j]."</div>";
       }
       echo "</div>";
   }
?>
```

2:

```
<?php
   for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){
?>
       <div id='...' class='...Ä style='...'>
<?php  
       for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){
?>
           <div style='...'> <?php echo array[$i][$j]; ?> </div>
       <?php } ?>
       </div>
<?php   } ?>
```

Maybe someone has some additional tips how i can make the data visualization fast. I read some artical about MySQL structure and i believe my DB looks fine. So what i can do to optimize the reading of data.

Comment: for large  output you should use pagination ... output 1000 rows  seems not useful

Comment: thanks for your answer. of course i paginate the data. my code looks verry diffrent thats only the core code to figure out my problem

Comment: I have posted  some brief suggestion as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As scaisEdge said, paginate your data.
Moreover, there are several changes that can make your code faster.

1. count($foo) outside of for loop
2. use pre-increment instead of post
3. use 'str' and concatenation instead of "str"

Here is a "benchmark" (without output) :

```
<?php
$array = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 1000; ++$i){
    $array[] = range(0, 20, 1);
}

$t = microtime(true);
for($k = 0; $k < 5000; ++$k){
   for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){
       $a = "<div id='...' class='...Ä style='...'>";
       for($j=0; $j<count($array[$i]); $j++){
           $a = "<div style='...'>".$array[$i][$j]."</div>";
       }
       $a = "</div>";
   }
}
echo 'Count and post : ' . (microtime(true) - $t) . "\n";


$t = microtime(true);
for($k = 0; $k < 5000; ++$k){
   $c = count($array);
   for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++){
       $a = "<div id='...' class='...Ä style='...'>";
       $c2 = count($array[$i]);
       for($j=0; $j<$c2; $j++){
           $a = "<div style='...'>".$array[$i][$j]."</div>";
       }
       $a = "</div>";
   }
}
echo 'No count and post : ' . (microtime(true) - $t) . "\n";


$t = microtime(true);
for($k = 0; $k < 5000; ++$k){
   $c = count($array);
   for($i=0; $i<$c; ++$i){
       $a = "<div id='...' class='...Ä style='...'>";
       $c2 = count($array[$i]);
       for($j=0; $j<$c2; ++$j){
           $a = "<div style='...'>".$array[$i][$j]."</div>";
       }
       $a = "</div>";
   }
}
echo 'No count and pre : ' . (microtime(true) - $t) . "\n";


$t = microtime(true);
for($k = 0; $k < 5000; ++$k){
   $c = count($array);
   for($i=0; $i<$c; ++$i){
       $a = '<div id="..." class="...Ä style="...">';
       $c2 = count($array[$i]);
       for($j=0; $j<$c2; ++$j){
           $a = '<div style="...">'.$array[$i][$j].'</div>';
       }
       $a = '</div>';
   }
}
echo 'No count and pre and \' : ' . (microtime(true) - $t) . "\n";

// @scaisEdge
$t = microtime(true);
for($k = 0; $k < 5000; ++$k){
   foreach($array as $subarray){
       $a = '<div id="..." class="...Ä style="...">';
       foreach($subarray as $v){
           $a = '<div style="...">'.$v.'</div>';
       }
       $a = '</div>';
   }
}
echo 'Foreach : ' . (microtime(true) - $t) . "\n";

?>
```

This outputs :

```
Count and post : 46.050459861755
No count and post : 30.590306043625
No count and pre : 29.880299091339
No count and pre and ' : 29.930299043655
Foreach : 29.120290994644
```

As weird as it looks, ' seems to be slower than ".
PHP checks " strings variables inside and replace it whereas ' string are just... string. No operation performed.

Has someone an idea of this slowness ?

Comment: hey thank your for the answer and the provement by your time results. i changed my for loops to foreach. the browser needs only half of time now. u know why is foreach fast as for loops or you have a link or something like that. i want to understand what happened

Comment: As scaisEdge to in his comment of his post, PHP uses its internal array iterator of array. Which is technically faster. I cannot explain it more precisely as I have not study this part of zend engine.

Answer (score 1):

For large output you should use pagination ... output 1000 rows seems not useful
If you paginate your result is more equal to the firts that to the last .

But you can do somethings for the code  .. you should count the result just one time and not for all cycle of the loop 
so instead of `for($i=0; i<count($array); $i++){`

you should use

```
$numElem =count($array);
for($i=0; $i<$numElem; $i++){
     .......
}
```

or use

```
 foreach ( $array as $key => $value ){
  ......
 }
```

these are much faster

Comment: Foreach seems to be faster than for. See the "benchmark" on my post : `Foreach : 29.120290994644`

Comment: @zenko   tipcally foreach si more  faster that  for .. foreach use the iterator  ..